# Print monitor modification and redirection to another printer port

Tags: windows, printing, driver, monitor

I'm trying to modify the data being printed to an **Epson POS** printer before it is printed.  I'm currently doing this by using a *print monitor* instead of the *Epson port* in the printer port config.  In the `WritePort()` routine for the monitor, I am writing the modified data to `COM1` directly.  This does send the data to the printer, but it is not doing the negotiation with the printer that is done if the *Epson port* is selected instead of the port monitor.

Is there a way to send the data from my monitor through the *Epson port* in order to get the real driver to kick in?  It seems to be a monitor as well as it shows up in the list returned from `EnumMonitors()`.

I've seen similar questions asked, but I've been unable to find the answer on any forum.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got an answer for this question?